# Cart price rule when buying two items of a specific product

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I try to develop a cart price rule for the following scenario: I offer a configurable product in three sizes, i.e. SKU Product_A for the parent and SKU Product_A_Medium, Product_A_Large and Product_A_Xlarge for the children. If a customer buys at least two items of the product (regardless of the size), I would like to offer a 10% discount on each of the products.

I created this rule:

**Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met**

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true:
Quantity in cart equals or greater than 2
SKU is Product_A

**Actions**

Apply Precent of product price discount
Discount Amount 10

**Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions**

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE
SKU is Product_A

It works fine whenever a customer buys at least two items of the same size. However, I want the rule to be applied also in case the customer choses 2 items of a different size. Is it possible? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using **ANY** instead of **All**

Comment: Using Any instead of All works. I found an alternative solution seconds ago:

If ALL of these conditions TRUE
If total quantity equals or greater than 2 for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL of these conditions
SKU is Product_A